# How to do a Twitter redirect "domain.com/test" to "domain.com/#!/test" with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, twitter

I am looking for a way to do a redirect like Twitter does using htaccess.
All requests to "domain.com/test" should be redirected to "domain.com/#!/test"
Should also work with "domain.com/test1/test2" -> "domain.com/#!/test1/test2"
Any ideas?
Thnx

Comment: I'd say it would use JavaScript to redirect to root and then add the hashbang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do that with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.location.replace('/#!/test');
//]]>
</script>
```

To comply with terms of graceful degradation you should do that with JavaScript too.

Comment: Then why, if you visit e.g. http://twitter.com/test with JavaScript turned OFF, does it still redirect you to https://twitter.com/#!/test?